# Volley:time out error occurred

Tags: android, android-volley

volley library:

My question is whether Api will be called after the time out error occurred or it will not attempt to call the Api after error ocurrred??

need help..
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be triggered but its causes when the low network situation or server is not responding to the corresponding  request.

Comment: @user1368334..are u sure it will be triggered after the error occurred!!??

Comment: after error occurred its not triggered.if you get time out error means server not responding.